# React Native use Context in helper api file from within different exported functions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a helper file with some exported functions.
And I have a ContextProvider with some shared data.
Now I need to change the Data in the Context from inside the helper functions.

But there are errors if I call the useContext statement inside the function bodys and also if I do it outside.

If I create one default function MyHelper() in the helper file I can call the useContext inside and its working.
But then I can't use different functions as api from another file. Only the MyHelper().

How can I call more than one exported functions in another .js File and also change there context data?

I have made an example code which shows my problem without the overhead of my original code:

MyScreen.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {View, Button} from 'react-native';

import {MyContext} from '../MyProvider'; // assume this exists and is working
import {myChangeNameFunction} from '../helpers/MyHelper';

const MyScreen = () => { 
  const {name, setName} = useContext(MyContext); // does work here
  
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title={name} //just as easy example
        onPress={() => myChangeNameFunction('test')}
      />
   </View>
      
  );
}

export default MyScreen;
```

MyHelper.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {MyContext} from '../MyProvider';
    
    //const {name, setName} = useContext(MyContext); // does not work
    
    export const myChangeNameFunction = (test) => { 
        //const {name, setName} = useContext(MyContext); // does not work
        setName(test);
    }
    
    export const anotherFunction = (test) => { 
        //const {name, setName} = useContext(MyContext); // does not work
        setName(test);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Maybe a better example:

MyScreen.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import GeocoderOsm from 'react-native-geocoder-osm';
import {MyContext} from '../MyProvider';
//import {getGPSbyAddress} from '../helpers/MyHelper'; 
// I want to exclude functions below and instead import them from helper file 

const MyScreen = () => { 
  const {address, setAddress} = useContext(MyContext);
  
  // imagine here are a lot of functions like these below.
  // I want to exclude them from this file to a MyHelper.js
  // So the MyScreen.js File is not so big and with chaos.
  // Also I could import and reuse these functions from other Screens than MyScreen.js.
  
  const getGPSbyAddress = (place) => { 
      GeocoderOsm.getGeoAddress(place).then((res) => {
      // setAddress is working here. But if I outsource the function to MyHelper.js File 
      // I can't access the setAddress in the Context. And I also can't return 
      // the res output because its kind of async - because of the then() function 
      // of the OSM lib. So I just want to save it to context if its finished.
        setAddress(res);    
      }).catch((e) => { 
        console.log('error', e)
      });
  }
  
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title='Get GPS'
        onPress={() => getGPSbyAddress('London') }
      />
      <Text>{address}</Text>
   </View>
      
  );
}

export default MyScreen;
```

MyHelper.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import GeocoderOsm from 'react-native-geocoder-osm';
import {MyContext} from '../MyProvider';
    
  //const {address, setAddress} = useContext(MyContext); // does not work here
    
  export const getGPSbyAddress = (place) => { 
      //const {address, setAddress} = useContext(MyContext); // does not work here
      
      GeocoderOsm.getGeoAddress(place).then((res) => {
        setAddress(res);    // this is not working here because I cant call useContext anywhere.
      }).catch((e) => { 
        console.log('error', e)
      });
  }
  
  export const getAddressByGPS = (lat, lon) => { 
      //const {address, setAddress} = useContext(MyContext); // does not work here
      
      GeocoderOsm.getGeoCodePosition(lat, lon).then((res) => {
        setAddress(res);    // this is not working here because I cant call useContext anywhere.
      }).catch((e) => { 
        console.log('error', e)
      });
  }
  
  // ... a lot of more functions
```

So if there is no solution to set the Context from the functions in the MyHelper.js File... How can i then outsource some functions in an seperate file (for better reading and reuse) and also get my {address} rendered with the fetched data from the outsourced function which probably fetched the address asyncly. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: In case I call useContext inside the functions its: "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."
In case I call useContext outside its the same.
In case I create only one MyHelper function and use it inside this, the error says "undefined" because the context hook is outside the scope of the called function.

Comment: Add all the code for `MyHelper.js`.

Comment: `useContext` is a react hook. It needs to be called inside of a react component. You can however compose your own custom hook (a function) using the built-in hooks. But again this hook would still need to be called inside of a component. The naming convention for custom hooks it that they should start with `use` for the hooks linter plugin to work.

Comment: @yudhiesh thats all.

Comment: @trixn I would prefer this context hook and i would also call it inside a component. But the other question is then how to export the functions from inside the component? At the end I just want to call a function which is in MyHelper.js call it from MyScreen.js and change the context data in this function. If its a component or class or bunch of functions is not important for me. I just want to outsource some functions from my MyScreen.js file. Thank you.

Comment: @MarioGotti I'm not sure what you gain by doing this. All you do in your example is to wrap `setName` in another function that does nothing else then calling `setName`. Why not call `setName` directly in your component?

Comment: @trixn This is just here in this example created for this question. In the real project there is happening more inside the functions. And I want to reuse these functions from different Screen Files.

Comment: @MarioGotti You can combine as many hooks as you like in a custom function which is itself a hook and has to follow the same rules as every hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see the error is that you are calling a hook outside of the component body. In your case that is the `useContext` hook. In the first case you are calling it on a module level and in the other two cases you call it inside of a function but then you call that function in a handler which is also "outside" of the component. What you need to do is to extract a hook that you call unconditionally in your component. That hook can expose (return) a function that you can call in your handler.

You can create your own custom hooks which are composed from other hooks:

MyHelper.js

```
import {MyContext} from '../MyProvider';

export const useName = () => {
    return useContext(MyContext);
}
```

You can then use it in a component. Note that the custom hook has to return everything that the component needs to use.

MyScreen.js

```
import {useName} from '../helpers/MyHelper';

const MyScreen = () => { 
  const {name, setName} = useName();
  
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title={name}
        onPress={() => setName('test')}
      />
   </View>
      
  );
}
```

In this case the `useName` hook will implicitly use `MyContext` without explicitly having to pass it. It could of course contain many more hooks and return the relevant values as needed by components using it.

EDIT

Given your more detailed example you would create a custom hook in your MyHelper.js file, which returns all those functions needed. It can't work any different as those functions need the context in the first place. They are closures over data from your context. So as your helper needs to first get the context it needs to call `useContext` which makes it a hook.

MyHelper.js

```
import {MyContext} from '../MyProvider';

export const useUserData = () => {
    const {
        name, setName,
        address, setAddress
    } = useContext(MyContext);

    const myChangeNameFunction = test => setName(test);

    const getGPSbyAddress = (place) => { 
        GeocoderOsm.getGeoAddress(place).then((res) => {
            setAddress(res);    
        }).catch((e) => { 
            console.log('error', e)
        });
     }

     const getAddressByGPS = (lat, lon) => {   
         GeocoderOsm.getGeoCodePosition(lat, lon).then((res) => {
             setAddress(res);   
         }).catch((e) => { 
             console.log('error', e)
         });
     }

     // return your data and updater functions 
     // so you can access them in your component
     return {
         name, address, 
         getGPSbyAddress, getAddressByGPS, myChangeNameFunction
     };
}
```

You can use your custom hook like that:

MyScreen.js

```
import {useUserData} from '../helpers/MyHelper';

const MyScreen = () => { 
    const {
        name, address, 
        getGPSbyAddress, myChangeNameFunction
    } = useUserData();

    return (
        <View>
            <Button
                title='Get GPS'
                onPress={() => getGPSbyAddress('London') }
            />
            <Text>{address}</Text>
            <Button
                title={name}
                onPress={() => myChangeNameFunction('test')}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

You can of course use that hook in multiple different components simultanously. You can also split this custom hook into multiple hooks that only have certain functions that are related.

Comment: Thanks but it does not solve my problem. The problem is not to get a context from MyHelper to MyScreen. The problem is to outsource functions from MyScreen to MyHelper. Because in the real example there are maybe 20 functions. I just want them in another file. Thats working so far. But some of them use a set-function to set data to the context. From MyScreen I can access the Context. But if I outsource the functions, I can't access as I found no way so far.

Comment: @MarioGotti It's completely unclear what you mean. You can move as many functions to MyHelpers as you want in the exact same way presented in my answer. But as soon as those functions use a hook they are hooks itself and therefore need to follow the rules of hooks.

Comment: @MarioGotti Maybe you could add a better example that illustrates your use case better?

Comment: @MarioGotti You can't call `setName` without getting it from the context first. Also there shouldn't be a function that directly calls `setName` in your `MyHelper.js` file because this would mean it gets called during render. Instead the helper function should return a function itself that you can call in your component. The confusion is most likely between plain helper functions and functions that use hooks internally (aka custom hooks). The outsourced helper in your example should not call `setName` but expose a function that calls `setName` when called in your component.

Comment: @MarioGotti `setState` functions are bound to the hook that created them. You need to call that hook in one or another way before using it. And you should only call `setState` in a handler or effect, not during render.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have edited my start post for an update with another bigger example and more comments. Hope it helps you better to understand what I want to do.

Comment: @MarioGotti I updated my answer with a solution to your more detailed example.

Comment: @MarioGotti I hope it makes more sense for you now. The point is that these functions are closures over values from the context. You can't just put them somewhere else without having these values in the scope they are defined in. In this case the scope around them needs to be a hook. You can of course further extract functions from this but they can't call `setName` or `setAddress`. You would have to provide those as parameters and still need some form of closure in your hook that calls them. This is just how composition with hooks works. There is no way to get around that.

Comment: Alright I think I understand. Thank you very very much. I think I can work with this example and edit my real app to use the hooks this way.

Comment: I have edited my app now and its working fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarioGotti I am also having trouble in keeping my state and business logic separate from UI. I really liked angular services in this regard as they keep the state and all helper, data fetching methods at one place and components can easily use and share them. But this way of defining context and then defining custom hook to use that context in fetch API's etc seems unnecessarily complicated. I want a separate service/helper for my fetch api's that is aware of the state. Any suggestions please

Comment: @artsnr I have posted an answer below with an example. Maybe its useful for you.

Comment: Is it possible to pass a function as parameter to useUserData and use it inside it?

Comment: @billysk Yes, this would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Another example for using Helper file and access global context:

FetchHelper.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {Context} from '../ContextProvider';

export const FetchHelper = () => {
    const {globaldata, setGlobaldata} = useContext(Context); 

    const fetchDataA = async () => {  
        d = await getDataFromDB(); 
        return d; // return value
    }

    const fetchDataB = async () => {  
        d = await getDataFromDB(); 
        setGlobaldata(d); // set value in global context
        return;
    }

    return {
        fetchDataA, fetchDataB
    };
}
```

MyScreen.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import {Context} from '../ContextProvider';
import {FetchHelper} from '../helpers/FetchHelper';

const MyScreen = () => { 

    const {globalData, setGlobalData} = useContext(Context);    // make global context accessable

    const {fetchDataA, fetchDataB} = FetchHelper(); // make helper functions accessable 

    const fetchData = async () => {  
        
        // variation A: call helper function and await returned value. Set it in global context data here.
        
        const dataA = await fetchDataA(); 
        setGlobalData(dataA);
        
        // variation B: call helper function and global context data is set in helper function.
        
        fetchDataB();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchData();
    }, []);

    return ();
};

export default MyScreen;
```

Comment: That's quite helpful. Kindly clear me few concepts about custom hooks state: 1) The components who use custom hook have their isolated hook state right. So what about useContext state we are using in hook, that should be global shouldn't it?
Also If a component is importing only one state variable from custom hook, will it re-render if other state variables change in hook? when exactly component using hook re-renders