# How to organize/manage context state and helper functions (mainly API calls) in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-state-management, react-context

I want to organize my react native app such that all state and business logic related to one module remains encapsulated at one place and components can focus mainly on UI. I really liked angular services in this regard as they keep the state and all helper, data fetching methods at one place and components can easily use and share them.
I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66712670/9399066)
But this way of defining context and then defining custom hook to use that context in fetch API's etc seems unnecessarily complicated. I want a separate service/helper for my fetch api's that is aware of the state. Any suggestions please

For example almost every app has auth module. I have defined auth context:

```
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useContext,
  useMemo,
  createContext,
} from "react";
import { externalBaseURI2 } from "../config/constants";
import StorageService from "../services/storageService";

const AuthContext = createContext({
  token: null,
});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getAuthToken()
    .then(token => {
      if(token) setToken(token)
    })
  }, []);
  
  const getAuthToken = () => {
    if (token) return Promise.resolve(token);
    else return StorageService.getDataFromStorage("authToken");
  };

  const setAuthToken = (accessToken) => {
    setToken(accessToken);
    StorageService.setDatatoStorage("authToken", accessToken);
  };

  const revokeAuthToken = () => {
    setToken(null);
    StorageService.removeItemFromStorage("authToken");
  };


**///////////////////// BELOW ARE MY STATE FUNCTIONS i.e: login, getProfile, logOut ////////////////**

  const actions = {
      login: (email, pass) => {
        console.log(email, pass);
        return fetch(`${externalBaseURI2}/auth/login`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: pass }),
        })
        .then((response) => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            return response.json().then(error => {
              throw new Error(error.message || error.errorMsg)
            })
            // throw new Error("Something went wrong");
          }
          return response.json()
          .then((jsonResponse) => {
            setAuthToken(jsonResponse.token);
            return jsonResponse;
          })
        })
        
        // .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      },
      getProfile: () => {
        return getAuthToken()
        .then(token => {
          if(token) {
            return fetch(`${externalBaseURI2}/api/profile`, {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
              },
            })
          }
          else throw new Error('User not logged in')
        })
        .then((response) => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            return response.json().then(error => {
              throw new Error(error.message || error.errorMsg)
            })
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((jsonResponse) => {
          return jsonResponse;
        })
      },
      logOut: () => {
        revokeAuthToken()
      }
    }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token, ...actions }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useAuth must be inside a Provider with a value");
  }
  return context;
};
```

Here I have login and getprofile methods as state functions. Which I don't think should be responsible for fetching api data instead should only be responsible for setting state like logOut method. So where should I put the API fetch methods (in some helper/service file not in component) where I can access the state token too (to send in private api calls).

Comment: Please try using this library [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/). We can wrap API calls within custom hooks using this library, and then we can simply use those hooks within context.